# create-react-app: using non-npm dependencies / libraries

Tags: reactjs

I'm using Create React App and I would like to use a JS library that isn't available via npm.  How would I go about integrating that into my app?  I think I can simply add a script tag for it in `public/index.html` for development purposes but I'm guessing that won't include it in the final build code.  Any suggestions would be welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add your script to the `public` folder and include it in the `public/index.html` file.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="%PUBLIC_URL%/my-script.js"></script>
```

Comment: That appears to work - thanks!  However, does that mean when I run `npm run build`, that this non-npm library will be included in my production ready code?

Comment: @Bill That's right. Everything in the `public` folder will be copied to the final `build` folder you use in production.

Comment: Ahh, OK.  Thanks again for your help!  As an old school jQuery developer, I'm finding this whole npm/webpack/build process daunting (and so far IMHO somewhat unnecessarily complicated).  But I'm liking React.

Comment: @Bill No problem! Yeah, it's quite the hassle in the beginning, but it's hard to go back to manually adding scripts when you get the hang of just `npm i -S something`,  `import Something from 'something';`